# ruby display delete if product= user product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have  a little problem with a display of a "delete button" i would like that only the user who have post the product can see the button delete so i have try to do a methode who compared id :

```
def user_publis?
 @user=current_user
 @publication_id = @publication.user.id
 @user_id= @user.id
 @publication_id = @user_id
end
```

a méthode who ask if the publication have build by the current_user

```
def user_publis?
  if @publication=current_user.publications.build
     content_tag( :span ,class: "btn btn-rounded") do
     content_tag( "my delete button")
     end
  end
```

but no one are good....

thx for help and sorry for my english ..^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write something like this in your view:

```
<% if @publication.user == current_user %>
  <span class="btn btn-rounded">
  my delete button...
<% end %>
```

**Or:** You can add the following method to your `Publication`:

```
def published_by?(user)
  self.user == user
end
```

and use it in your view like:

```
<% if @publication.published_by? current_user %>
  <span class="btn btn-rounded">
  my delete button...
<% end %>
```

Comment: perfect xD  why do complicate when it's simple ..^^ thank's you  :)